# Getting only start of articles out of a database

Tags: spring, jpa, model-view-controller

In a Spring Boot Web MVC application, I have a page with an overview of articles, and one with article details.

The article's content should be limited to a certain length inside the overview, it should be its normal length in the article details page.

Where would be the best place to "cut off" the rest of the article? Somehow in the SQL query? In the @Service class that retrieves the overview? Inside my view? I'd say in the view, simply because I feel that should contain the view logic.

I use a @Repository with Spring JPA for the data retrieval. I use thymeleaf for my frontend pages.

Comment: OK, I need a bit more information before I can give a definitive answer. What does your repository look like now? Do you get a list of articles for the Overview page? What's the query for that? What other information about the article do you need to get in this list? How is the text of the article defined in the database? CLOB?

Comment: For the article in the list, I just need the date, title, and start of the content. The content itself is in a TEXT type in the DB (mysql). The query is a typical SELECT a from Article a; Right now I just have a String getSummary() { return this.getArticleText().subString(0, Math.max(this.getArticleText().length(), 500)); } method in my Article Domain class (which my persistency layer/repository returns) that I use